# React native AsyncStorage bad response

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Have created React Native app and ned to use AsyncStorage to benefit from it's storage mechanism.

To save in AsyncStorage use code:

```
  _storeData = async (param) => {
    try {
      let par = JSON.stringify(param);
      //await AsyncStorage.setItem(this.key, par);
      Utilities.setItem(this.key, par);
      this._retrieveData();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  };
```

To retrieve data:

```
 _retrieveData = async () => {
    try {      
      const value = Utilities.getItem(this.key);
      if (value !== null) {
        alert('data is new: ' + JSON.stringify(value));
      }
    } catch (error) {
    }
  };
```

And, to setItem and getItem in Utilities partial:

```
const setItem = (key, value) => {
  if (!key || !value) return;
  AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
};

const getItem = (key) => {
  if (!key) return;
  var val = AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
  return val;
};
```

Data is being saved, but response I'm getting does not look correctly, as it's a string of 'weird' characters:

```
{"_40":0,"_65":0,"_55":null,"_72":null}
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting such answer?

Comment: `getItem` is also async - the weird characters represent the promise being returned by `getItem` - should be `var val = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);` and your `getItem` function should be marked `async`. You'll need to `await` on any calls to `Utilities.getItem` and `Utilities.setItem` as well.

Comment: thank you, works perfectly, pls post your response as answer not comment and will approve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `AsyncStorage.getItem` is also async - the weird characters represent the promise being returned by `getItem`.

Use `var val = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);` and mark your `getItem` utility function as `async`. You'll need to `await` on any calls to `Utilities.getItem` and `Utilities.setItem` as well.